# Transform matrix to scale away from/towards an arbitrary plane in 3D space

Tags: matrices, geometry, 3d

I'm not entirely sure if this belongs in Mathematics or GameDev. I'm trying Mathematics first, so please let me know if it's in the wrong place.

In 3D space, I have a plane `A` given by 3 points `A1`, `A2`, and `A3`, and I need a transform matrix `M` to scale arbitrary points so their distance to the plane changes by a factor `x`, along the normal of the plane.

The plane doesn't necessarily pass through the origin so homogeneous coordinates are necessary.

So far I only have convoluted solutions (e.g. rotate and translate plane to match xy plane, scale along z, then reverse rotation and translation) and feel something simpler is possible.

Comment: If you have the matrices for your "convoluted solution," then the "simple" solution you see is just the product of those matrices.

Answer (score 0):

A normal to the plane can be calculated by $n = (A_2 - A_1)\times(A_3 - A_1)$. The unit normal is then $\hat n = \frac n{\|n\|}$ The distance from the plane to the origin is $d = \hat n \cdot A_1$ (or $A_2$ or $A_3$). Thus the equation for points $v$ in the plane is $$\hat n \cdot v = d$$
And the distance of some arbitrary point $w$ from the plane is given by $\hat n \cdot w - d$. More generally, the projection of $w$ onto the plane is $$\widetilde w = w - (\hat n \cdot w - d)\hat n$$

So if we want $w_x$ to a point on the same normal line from the plane passing through $w$, but at a distance of $x$ times the distance of $w$ from the plane, then it would be given by $\widetilde w + x(\hat n \cdot w - d)\hat n$, or:
$$\begin{align}w_x &= w - (\hat n \cdot w - d)\hat n+ x(\hat n \cdot w - d)\hat n\\&= w -(1 - x)(\hat n \cdot w - d)\hat n\end{align}$$